# Ionicons are shown in web application but the icons are not displayed properly in the hybrid mobile app

Tags: web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app, ionicons

ionicons are displayed like a box with border in hybrid mobile app but the icons are displayed prefectly in the web application. I referred [some ionicons not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766015/some-ionicons-not-showing) but it didnt help.

Comment: I believe it is a path issue to the `ionicons` in your css file, please share path you are using.

Comment: I have used http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css cdn link and even tried directly inclulding the css file. This works fine with web app but not with mobile.In mobile it shows a black bordered box

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, no ionicons in Firefox, IE or mobile.
Had the ionicons.css linked correctly in the header to my /fonts folder but did not upload the .woff, .eot, .svg, .ttf files from the initial font pack of ionicons/fonts folder.

Also make sure the files are linked to the correct path in your uploaded ionicons.css file.

Hope this helps!